# What is this device? (Constant level device?)

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, water, equipment, water-treatment

Found this in my lab on a random shelf (water quality lab). It is old enough that nobody knows where it came from. I think it's a constant level device. It has in- and out-flow connections, as well as electrical plugs for some kind of monitoring equipment. The only writing is on the glass, which says "FSTREEM [ASTREEM?] MADE IN ENGLAND". The inside float looks like it is meant to float up and down, while the thin metal wire keeps track of its level via a small electric recorder. What is this thing called, and where can I find more info?
[image: I think its a constant level device]
Thanks!

Comment: FiStream  https://www.google.com/search?q=old+seismograph&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS511US512&espv=2&biw=897&bih=873&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF_eO6z6bRAhVB5GMKHTmTBhkQ_AUIBigB&dpr=1#tbm=isch&q=FSTREEM+glass+&imgrc=_

Comment: I sent FiStream an Email with a picture.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Joseph. Knowing that it is a Fi-Streem product, I called/emailed them and got an answer from their friendly support tech. From his email response: [This] is a "Switch Level Device, front" that is used in conjunction with an older series Fi-Streem (Fisions) Still, which is no longer manufactured. The part number for this item is, 06756."